# VirtualBox isn't locked when Ubuntu is locked

Tags: virtualbox, lock-screen

I have win7 in my VirtualBox 4.2.10 in my Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 .
My ubuntu is locked in 5 minutes but I can still use win7 when win7 is set fullscreen.
I can unlock the ubuntu only after I close or minimize the win7.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtually logic.  :-) - when you want lock the system inside virtualbox. Then the system there is locked "locally" (or virtually). Would mean that program virtualbox needs for each installed OS a lock to be built-in within program virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I've experienced the same and the reason for this is quite simple, if you have Windows 7 on your VirtualBox and it is running, i.e, you're working on it, it won't get locked. It same works in the converse too, so it's not an issue with Ubuntu, nor is it a bug.